# Timeout for Multipart HTTP post

Tags: http, timeout, connection, multifile-uploader, android-internet

How to set the timeout for HTTP multipart file post. I want to upload image to the server at the time internet connection is not there how to handle that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution for that here is the code to set the timeout for HTTPClient

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

int timeoutConnection = 30000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,timeoutConnection);

int timeoutSocket = 30000;

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

Comment: please give suggestion if you find better solution.